# Run docker from powershell script, and passing `--env` variable if is set

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell, docker

I'm trying to port a bash script to powershell. In bash, I have:

`docker run --env MYVARIABLE ...`
If MYVARIABLE is set, then it will be passed to docker run, otherwise it will be omitted. 
Is it possible to simulate the same behavior from powershell?

On my linux host I have in my env `EDITOR=vim`.
So If I run a docker instance with this variable, it will push it in the env:

```
docker run -it --rm --env EDITOR --env EDITOR_VAR_NOT_EXISTS debian:stretch-slim env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=2ff94a96ef77
TERM=xterm
EDITOR=vim
HOME=/root
```

I've tried the same on Windows, but it's not working.